# Scraping a website that URL doesn't change when clicking on "next page" button

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a BBC website

https://www.bbc.com/news/topics/c95yz8vxvy8t/hong-kong-anti-government-protests

and I would like to get all the news articles. But the URL doesn't change when clicking on the next page button so I can only get the first page information. Can anyone help? I'm using Selenium but familiar with requests too. Thanks!

Comment: When the button is clicked, the page content changes, even though the url stays the same.  Why are you expecting the url to change?

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm trying to scrape the entire website. Since the URL doesn't change, I can only scrape the first page.

Comment: I don't understand.  When a human visits that page and clicks the next button, the page refreshes with new content, and the human happily continues reading the new stories.  Why can't your code do the same?

Answer (score 1):

use developer console in your browser, go to networks tab, disable cache.
you can see api requests being made for each page change. you dont need selenium, you can just use requests or aiohttp.

this is an example:
https://push.api.bbci.co.uk/batch?t=%2Fdata%2Fbbc-morph-lx-commentary-data-paged%2Fabout%2Fd5803bfc-472d-4abf-b334-d3fc4aa8ebf9%2FisUk%2Ffalse%2Flimit%2F20%2FnitroKey%2Flx-nitro%2FpageNumber%2F2%2Fversion%2F1.5.6?timeout=5

type "batch" in the filter bar and you should see only the api calls I believe to be responsible for page change.

you can get the about id(d5803bfc-472d-4abf-b334-d3fc4aa8ebf9) of this topic in the webpage source. in this case in,  https://www.bbc.com/news/topics/c95yz8vxvy8t/hong-kong-anti-government-protests